# передача в awk переменной из for цикла bash

Tags: bash, awk

Есть неработающая строка

```
whois ya.ru |for i in 6 13 14 15 16 17; do  awk 'NR==$i{print $1 "\t\t"  $2}'; done;
//в выводе пусто
```

Задача заключается в выводе 6 13 14 15 16 17 строк из вывода whois
Если заменить $i на 6 - то все работает отлично:

```
whois ya.ru |for i in 6 13 14 15 16 17; do  awk 'NR==6{print $1 "\t\t"  $2}'; done;
domain:         YA.RU
```

вопрос, собственно в том, как передать значения из цикла в NR,
либо как вовсе обойтись без цикла

Comment: я и история вопроса, будем благодарны, если кто-нибудь, в комментарии ниже сможет переместить for цикл внутрь awk,пока что у меня ничего не выходит

Comment: Решайте целиком на awk -- он как раз для подобных задач.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
whois ya.ru | sed -n '6p;13,17p'
```

`-n` говорит sed что бы по умолчанию не печатал строки, после чего просим их печатать (`p`) для 6й строки и для диапазона с 13 до 17. Хотя я бы предложил все таки ориентироваться на содержимое строк whois, а не на их порядок:

```
whois ya.ru | grep -E 'domain:|paid-till:|created:|free-date:|source:'
```

**UPD**

Вариант в awk:

```
whois ya.ru | awk 'NR==6 || NR==13,NR==17{print $1 "\t\t" $2}'
```

Comment: круто, спасибо! это легкое и простое решение проблемы,но хотелось бы на будущее разобраться и с взаимодействием bash-а и awk, в чем собственно заключается ошибка передачи аргумента.

Comment: а можно ли, с помощью sed, отсеять текстовый вывод идущий в выводе 
   
 whois google.com 
до строки domain: google.com? то есть увесистый массив текстовой информации?

Comment: @EnginerRod Для начала попробуйте `for i in 6 13 14 15 16 17; do  echo '$i'; done;` увидите 6 раз `$i`, потому что в параметрах в одинарных кавычках переменные не интерполируются. Если кавычки замените на двойные - увидите числа. Но awk после этого еще чего то не нравится, в нем я не разбираюсь

Comment: @EnginerRod Ну например `sed '/domain/p;1,/domain/d;'` приходится domain сначала печатать, потом удалять с 1 строки до него, потому что иначе его то же удалит. Хотя у того "увесистого массива информации" в первой позиции стоит знак '%', проще grep удалять строки начинающиеся на этот символ

Comment: @EnginerRod И кстати идея с awk в цикле не рабочая по определению. цикл же будет его 6 раз запускать. А уже при первом запуске он прочитает полностью то, что пришло на стандартный ввод и при втором запуске на вводе уже ничего не будет

Comment: можно ли, в таком случае передать в NR список строк? наподобие NR == [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, если отвечать на вопрос, который задали изначально, то это выглядит так:

```
for st in `echo '1 2 3'`; do
    whois ya.ru | awk -v "st_num=$st" '{
        if(NR==st_num) {print $1 "\t\t" $2};
    }'
done
```